# How to combine arrays in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
    A   B   C   D
1   1   2       
2   11  12  13  14
3   3   4       
4   1   warning
```

Inside A4, I put `=F.TEST({1,2,3,4},{11,12,13,14})`, the result is 1.
However, inside B4, I put `=F.TEST({A1,B1,A3,B3},{A2,B2,C2,D2})`, I got a warning saying that "There's a problem with this formula."

How should I combine `A1:B1` and `A3:B3` into one array, so that `F.TEST` works normally? I know I can insert another row and combine the first and third rows into one. But is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365:

```
=F.TEST(HSTACK(A1:B1,A3:B3),A2:D2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found that for vertical combination of arrays, there is `VSTACK`.